# Responsive button on top of banner using CSS

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I have a site I'm working on in wordpress/redesigning to be more responsive. And right now I have this button that sits on top of my banner, and it looks really nice, but when I shrink down the window it gets pushed down and eventually dissapears. I want it to look like the illustration below, where the button slowly moves downwards, and perhaps resizes a bit so it becomes smaller, where it finally sits on the bottom edge of the banner when its all the way shrunk. see picture:

[image: responsive site]

Here is my code for this, I want the class "get-order" (the button) to be responsive and move down. I'm a bit new to responsive design so what are some suggestions? I noticed the site I'm working on had some media queries, so I assume that is what I should use, I just don't really know the correct and most efficient CSS way to do it.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
<!--header-->
<div id="header">
<div class="wrap top-wrapper">
    <div class="menu" id="nav-wrap">

        <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
            <ul id="nav-wrap" class="nav">
                <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type   menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-23"><a href="example.com/"></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="example.com/products/">Products</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="example.com/become/">Become a member</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="example.com/the-blog/">Blog</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="example.com/about-us/">About us</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="example.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="logo">
        <a href="example.com">
            <img src="http://example.com/images/logo.png" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>

     <a href="#" class="get-order" title="derp"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="banner">
    <img src="example.com/images/banner_img.jpg" alt="" />
   </div>
</div>
<!--header/-->
</header><!-- #masthead -->




#header{ 
width:100%;
height:560px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:99;
position:relative;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.wrap {
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 955px;
z-index: 999;
}

.menu {
background: url("../../../images/nav-bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll left center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
min-height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
}

.nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 0 0 67px;
}

.nav li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.get-order {
 background-image: url("/images/b.png");
 height: 98px;
 left: 330px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 230px;
 width: 400px;
 z-index: 9;
}


.banner {
background-color: #060a0b;
display: inline-flex;
height: auto;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

.wrap,.wrap-2,.wrap-3,.wrap-4{ width:750px;}
.nav li a{padding:0 18px 0 0;}
#header{ height:310px;}
.nav{ padding: 20px 0 0 33px;}
.nav li a{padding: 0 16px 0 0;}
.banner{display:inherit;}
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px){

.wrap,.wrap-2,.wrap-3,.wrap-4{width:96%;}

.top-wrapper{ width:100%;}
.top-content{margin-top:20px;}

#menu-icon {
    color: #fff;        
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    background:url(../../../images/arrow3.png) no-repeat  95% 40% #161677;
    line-height:28px;
    font-family:'Roboto Slab',serif;
}


#navigation {
    clear: both;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 49px;
    /*width: 230px;*/
    width:100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
}

ul#nav-wrap{ display:none;}
.menu{ min-height:inherit;}
.nav{background:#f1f1f4;}
.nav li{ display:block; padding:5px 10px; float:none; background:none; border-top:1px solid #555559;  }
.nav li a{ color:#161677; font-size:14px;}
.nav li a.active, .nav li a:hover{ color:#303031;}
#header{ height:auto;}
.menu{position:inherit;}
.banner{ position:inherit;}
.wrap h1{padding-bottom:10px;}
.nav{ padding:0;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px){
.wrapper{ width:86%;}
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question asked last week, did you delete the old question, or did you just ask the same question again?

Comment: Both, I wasn't getting any responses I deleted and reposted it

Answer (score 0):

use css bottom function in your media queryi.e.

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px){
    .get-order {
      bottom: 0;
      height: x;
      left: x;
      width: x;
   }
}
```